# knowing the exact index clicked in a Flex tree event

Tags: apache-flex, events, tree

Please, i have a tree component that dispatches an `itemOpen` event.
 
When the black triangle next to the yellow folder is clicked, that folder opens to expose its children.

Is there anyway to know the index of the open folder? there is a `rowIndex` property in the target property of the `openItem` event that stores the index but it is not accessible. Does anyone knows or have come across situations like this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called itemRendererToIndex(itemRenderer:IListItemRenderer):int

ItemRenderer you can get from the dispatched event.

[Adobe Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#itemRendererToIndex%28%29)

Code smaple :

```
protected function tree1_itemOpenHandler(event:TreeEvent):void
{
 var index:int = tree.itemRendererToIndex(event.itemRenderer);
 trace(index);
}
```

Comment: There is one issue i discovered with the tree.itemRendererToIndex(event.itemRenderer), in a situation where the tree is populated with a nested XML or items, then, it becomes somehow preposterous where the root or parent XML is taken to be index 0 . that is ok if every item were aligned. so you would just have 0,1,2,..but suppose there is an XML with index 0 that has another element hidden in it . in that case, it wont be wise for that hidden element to be index 1 since itz not on the same level as the root XML. thatz the issue i discovered. anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always find the selectedItem using Tree(event.target).selectedItem. Thus, you can get the index of this item in your dataprovider. Hope it helps.

Comment: the Tree(event.target).selectedItem is always null since an item is not actually selected.